# Unable to find the GUI of SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk

I just installed Android Studio (latest) on my Windows 10. But I didn't find the GUI SDK Manager. I don't know how where it's located.

I looked in `C:\Users\**my username**\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools` but nothing.

Any help ???

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sorry to say that this questions posted here have to be related to code, not the tools around them.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer it is directly in the `Andoid\sdk` folder, not in the `Tools` sub directory:

`C:\Users\**my username**\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\SDK Manager.exe`

Comment: It's not there, no SDK Manager

Comment: maybe `C:\Android\android-sdk\tools`